# Swift 3: backwards video recording

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation, video-capture

i need to have the camera recording indefinetly and keep only the last minute of the recording, i dont know how to get the video clip from the buffer, im using AvFoundation, ive tried doing it frame by frame but i get memory issues, also ive tried saving 1 second clips and merging them later but it also crashed due to memory ussage, is there a way of achieving this? how? or is it impossible?